# Convert nested for loop in Java Lamda Expression with Condition

Tags: java

I am having a bit of trouble reducing this for loop into a stream in Java 8, the output from the stream does not match the for loop

```
    private static int getCount(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    int count=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(i));
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(list2.get(j));
            if(val1 != val2) {
                count =count+1;
            }
            else if(val1 == val2) {
                count =count-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: maybe it would help to see the **not-working** code too... otherwise that question is more like *give me the code*

Comment: @user85421 code is working. Just want to convert it into lamda expression

Comment: is working? "*the output from the stream does not match the for loop*"!  -- so it is a *give me the code* question - that is not what this site is for (and IMHO opinion, streams should not be for replacing for loops, more like to solve some problem in a more readable way {than for example a for loop})

Comment: @user85421 Updated my question. Copied complete method now help me to convert it into lamda expression

Comment: example for inner loop: `count += list2.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)                .map(v2 -> v2 == val1 ? -1 : +1).sum();` almost similar for the outer loop

Answer (score 1):

Stream version with two `map()` and `reduce()` methods for argument conversion and result accumulation:

```java
private static int getCount(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    return list1.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).reduce(1, (acc, val) -> {
        return list2.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).reduce(acc, (acc2, val2) -> {
            return acc2 + (val == val2 ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });
}
```

To make it more efficient and don't `parseInt()` elements of `list2` multiple times, an additional final variable can be used:

```java
private static int getCount(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    final List<Integer> list2Ints = list2.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).toList();
    return list1.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).reduce(1, (acc, val) -> {
        return list2Ints.stream().reduce(acc, (acc2, val2) -> acc2 + (val == val2 ? -1 : 1));
    });
}
```

Comment: I've added another answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to an additional request from the author:

1. Convert *second* array to the list of integers.
2. [Create stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) from the *first* array, map it to integers, and then reduce it to an `int` using the next step.
3. Reduce the *second* stream (from step #1) to a *resulting* `int` based on the first (`a` from list1) and second (`b` from list2) numbers, and the previously accumulated value.

```java
private int getCount(String[] list1, String[] list2) {
    final int x = 5;
    final List<Integer> bList = Arrays.stream(list2).map(Integer::parseInt).toList();
    
    return Math.abs(Arrays.stream(list1).map(Integer::parseInt).reduce(x, (xAcc, a) -> {
        return bList.stream().reduce(xAcc, (xAccLast, b) -> {
            return Math.min(Math.abs(a - b), xAccLast);
        });
    }));
}
```

Transformed from:

```java
private int getCount(String[] list1, String[] list2) {
    int x = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {
            int z = Integer.parseInt(list1[i]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(list2[j]);
            z = Math.abs(z - y);
            if (z < x)
                x = z;
        }
    }
    return Math.abs(x);
}
```